# Asus Discovery your computer and your wireless router are on a different subnet mask and I can't get to http://router.asus.com

Tags: asus

[image: subnet]

The router is connected to PC via LAN cable with a fixed IP address

[image: ip]

When I run `arp -a` then I see various IP for my iPhone (connected via USB) and ASUS Router

[image: arp]

But I can't get the router admin page to work with any IP I can find... What to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your router very likely has Wireless Isolation enabled which puts wired and wireless devices on different subnets.

Log into the Router (normally at 192.168.1.1 but also try http://router.asus.com) and then look under Wireless Professional settings and turn Wireless Isolation OFF.

[Wireless Isolation Settings](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044821/)

Go to http://router.asus.com >  [Wireless] >> [Professional]

then you can configure the [Set AP isolated] option to choose to (Yes or) **No**  (assuming you want it disabled.

Be sure to click [Apply] to save the configuration.

If you had made changes previously, you may wish to reset the Router to default settings and set it up again. I do this with my own routers to get a clean starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I shall have to reset the router to default to do this. Meanwhile, do you know how to tell the subnet mask of the PC itself?

Comment: A router only needs a subnet mask for the WAN connection (if it needs it at all).  Normally setting the internal (LAN) DHCP range sets the subnet properly. And starting with Default Settings is a good thing to do.